# How to fix AWSIoTPythonSdk.exception.AWSIoTException.subscribeTimeoutException

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to run  a script to connect to a iot topic on aws which has a custome message callback but the connection wont take place and throws the error mentioned in the question

This is for raspberry pi that uses aws iot for subscribing to a topic and receiving the custom message i have checked the endpoint its correct i have given only the partial code below

[image: this is the error]

```
# Custom MQTT message callback
def photoVerificationCallback(client, userdata, message):
print("Received a new message: ")
data = json.loads(message.payload)
try:
    similarity = data[1][0]['Similarity']
    print("Received similarity: " + str(similarity))
    if(similarity >= 90):
        print("Access allowed, opening doors.")
        print("Thank you!")
except:
    pass
print("Finished processing event.")

def checkRFIDNumber(rfidnumber):
return rfidnumber == '0004098554'

# Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect()
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.subscribe("rekognition/result", 1, 
photoVerificationCallback)
time.sleep(2)


# Publish to the same topic in a loop forever
while True:
print("waiting..")
scan = waitForRFIDScan()
print(scan)
if(checkRFIDNumber(scan)):
    print("RFID correct, taking photo...")
    uploadToS3(scan)
else:
    print("Bad RFID - Access Denied")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error message (with stack trace)

Comment: @hardillp sorry for the late update the error specified through the link if thats what you meant

Comment: Post and format the TEXT of the error not a picture, images are impossible to search for and hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not in the program it was in the configuration on the aws side once i fixed the policy it started working

i had to fix my iot policy that attaches to the certificates with 
iot:* for actions